# Muc-light with push notification support

Tags: objective-c, erlang, xmpp, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I've implemented muc light on mongooseIM chat server and can say good job to the team as this is exactly what we all wanted in mobiles world of group messaging.

1) Have anyone handled the push notification using this much light. As I have used the mod_zeropush for the single chat can I modify the same for supporting mod muc light as well.

2) Also how to handle mam on client side for the offline message as I understand from docs mod_offline can be used only for single chat and not muc light.

Thanks for any guidance given in advance.

Comment: Another option is MUC/Sub: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/ It is based on MUC XEP-0045 standard and allow standard MUC client and MUC/Sub client to join the same conversations.

Comment: I modified the mod_zero push erl and compiled to support the muc chat light message notifications to send to user.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the mod_zero push erl and compiled to support the muc chat light message notifications to send to user.

Also when the user wakes up and he gets the next message from the MUC light I fetch the group info to create the group and link rest messages (hence onwards) to this group.

For the previous messages I used the MAM directions as given in this [reference link](http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/open-extensions/muc_light/) for fetching the archived message from the server. Provided the server is enabled for muc_light message archive.